# AngularJS - form validation, v 1.4.8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

This is my first time using AngularJS, and the form validation is making me question my sanity. You would think this would be the easy part, but no matter how many ways I've tried Googling, the only thing that works is if I set a flag inside my controller's submit if the form is invalid to set the error class. I've looked at similar problems here, but none of them helped, so please do not simply dismiss this as a potential duplicate. Everything else has been a fail.

In the example mark up below I have reduced my form down to just one element. Here is what I have observed:

1. Using only `$error.required` does work. The `ng-class` { `'has-error' :registerForm.firstName.$error.required`} does outline the text box with the bootstrap has-ertror class, but this is on form load, which I do not want.
2. The `<p>` element with the error message will exhibit the same behavior, so I know that the message exists and is not malfored. It will also display if I only use `$error.required`. But as soon as I add `&& registerForm.$submitted` ( or `$isdirty` or `!notpristine` ) the message will not display on form submit. There are no errors (have developers tools open in chrome) and will post to the web API with no problem and return ok 200 or 400 if I send bad params.
3. I can write validation code inside my controller, checking if the field has a value and setting a flag on `$scope` such as `$scope.firstNameIsRequired` and that will work fine setting `ng-show="$scope.firstNameIsRequired"`, but that will remove testability.
   So the problem definitely has to be with how I am adding this in the markup. But after a weekend spent googling I am at my wits end. The only other thing different is that I am using a span on a click element to submit the form instead of an `input = submit`, but the `registerForm.$valid` function is setting the correct value. Do I somehow need to trigger the form validation in that `ng-click` directive?

I am using angular.js v 1.4.8.
I do have angular ui which has it's own validate, but that shouldn't interfere with the basic validation.

Here is the simplified markup:

```
<form name="registerForm" class="form-group form-group-sm" 
    ng-controller="userAccountController" novalidate>
<div class="form-group" 
        ng-class="{ 'has-error' : registerForm.firstName.$error.required }">
    <div><label>First Name</label> </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="" 
        ng-model="firstName" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="100" required=""/>
    <p ng-show="registerForm.firstName.$error.required && registerForm.$submitted" 
        class="alert alert-danger">First Name is required</p>
</div>  
    <div>
        <span class="btn btn-default" 
                ng-click="submit(registerForm.$valid)">Register</span>
    </div>
```

My controller code is

```
angular.module( "Application" ).controller( "userAccountController", [
"$scope", "userAccountService", function ( $scope, userAccountService)
{
    $scope.hasErrors = false;
    $scope.errorMessages = "";
    $scope.emailExists = true;
    $scope.clearErrors = function (){
        $scope.hasErrors = false;
    }

    $scope.onSuccess = function ( response ) {
        alert( "succeeded" );
    }

    $scope.submit = function (isValid) {
        if ($scope.registerForm.$invalid)
            return;
        alert("isvalid");
        $scope.clearErrors();
         var userProfile = $scope.createUser();
         userAccountService.registerUser(userProfile, $scope.onSuccess, $scope.onError);
    }

    $scope.createUser = function ()   {
        return {
            FirstName: $scope.firstName, LastName: $scope.lastName, Email: $scope.email,
            Password: $scope.password, SendAlerts: $scope.sendAlerts
        };
    };
}
]);
```

Any help will be appreciated. I probably just need a second set of eyes here because I have been dealing with this on and off since late Friday.

Comment: did you try ng-submit?

Comment: is this http://plnkr.co/edit/cXRBAvNTgneyFlwg5Qwe?p=preview work for you???

Comment: Thanks, but no luck there either. Changed the span ng-click to a submit input and added ng-submit="submit(registerForm.$valid)"

Comment: did you check my plunker?

Comment: I just did. I am seeing the exact same behavior, the validation is displayed when the form loads. I am starting to wonder if it is the angular/bootstrap setup.  Using grunt and npm is all new to me. Another dev on my team set that up and the karma test runner. Maybe there is something wrong there, perhaps a version conflict. When I asked him about angular form validation he said there wasn't any, so now I am really starting to wonder. I think I'll just hack this one using flags (I have that working onblur which is what I wanted) just so I can close the story and circle back later

Comment: I actually do not understand what you want to achieve... What I understood was dont popup error messages on submit??? correct me if I am wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in angular you want use the element.$valid to check wheter an model is valid or not - and you use element.$error.{type} to check for a specific validation error.

Keep in mind that the form.$submitted will only be set if the form is actually submitted - and if it has validationerrors it will not be submitted (and thus that flag is still false)

If you want to show errors only on submit you could use a button with type="submit" and bind to ng-click event - and use that to set a flag that the form has been validated. And handling the submit if the form is valid.

A short example with 2 textboxes, having required and minlength validation:

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myFormController", function($scope) {
    $scope.isValidated = false;
    $scope.submit = function(myForm) {
      $scope.isValidated = true;
      if(myForm.$valid) {
        console.log("SUCCESS!!");  
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.form-group {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.form-group.has-error {
  border: 1px solid red;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myFormController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': myForm.name.$invalid && isValidated}">
      <span>Name:</span>
      <input type="text" name="name" minlength="5" ng-model="name" required />  
      <span ng-if="myForm.name.$error.required && isValidated">Name is required</span>
      <span ng-if="myForm.name.$error.minlength && isValidated">Length must be atleast 5 characters</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': myForm.email.$invalid && isValidated}">
      <span>Email:</span>
      <input type="text" name="email" minlength="5" ng-model="email" required />  
      <span ng-if="myForm.email.$error.required && isValidated">Email is required</span>
      <span ng-if="myForm.email.$error.minlength && isValidated">Length must be atleast 5 characters</span>
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit" ng-click="submit(myForm)">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll give you the best answer, because it does solve the initial issue. I'm not using an actual input type submit element, I am instead using an ng-click on a span, but that does show that the form is invalid (registerForm.$valid shows the correct value). But that was just the first step. My goal was to figure out why the !$pristine or $dirty was not working because I wanted to fire the validation for each element on blur as well as on submit. But without solving that one, I have to go with the ugly solution which is an expansion on your isValid, basically a custom !.$pristine for each field

Comment: As on odd aside, $pristine works inside my controller.

Comment: $scope.validateForm = function() {
            if ($scope.firstName === undefined || (!$scope.$pristine && $scope.firstName.length === 0) )
                $scope.firstNameRequiredError = true;
        }

Comment: what you could do is creat a helper-directive that sets a specific field on the ng-model when you blur it, and just check for that field in the test. $dirty field is set as soon as a model is actually changed.

Comment: I may have to do that. I am finding this to be something I don't think I can solve in the mark up. I am now tracking both onblur and onfocus (onblur sets the input class to 'has-error' or 'has-success', reverting the input to no class on focus, and  ensuring that I fire all validators on submit but only the one currently raising the onblur event so that I don't show errors for fields that the user hasn't touched yet unless it is a submit event. And on the post to the web api I still need to handle any 400 responses (eg user name taken) coming from model state that I'm not checking on theclient

Comment: I would split the concerns here. Validating should be handeled every time the value changed - and rather add a separate flag on each field "displayErrors", which you set to true on blur (or when form is submitted) and back to "false" onFocus. (this could be handeled by a separate directive).

Comment: My controller is a simple api call but with all the validation (required fields, password and user name compare) it is 100 lines (with whitespace) of validation code and 10 lines to get the model and post it. This is definitely not a good separation of concerns. But I'm getting it to work and can show it to my client on Monday and deal with it after The flow I described above with changing the inputs element to error or success on blur and hiding the error message and removing either the error or the success class, along with the error messages seems like a nice user experience

Comment: $scope.firstNameOnBlur = function () {
            $scope.firstNameHasFocus = false;
            $scope.validateForm(false, $scope.firstName);
        }
        $scope.firstNameOnFocus = function()   {
            $scope.firstNameHasFocus = true;
        }

Comment: That gets repeated for every element, plus the validator functions. The boolean on $scope,validateForm indicates that it is not a full forn submission